# How to write a request body using a stream with the java 11 http client?

Tags: java, java-11, java-http-client

The legacy java http client provided an `OutputStream` using `URLConnection.getOutputStream`. Writing a json body for example worked like the following:

```java
final URLConnection urlConnection = ...;
try (OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream())) {
    new Gson().toJson(someJsonObject, writer);
}
```

What's the equivalent way of stream-writing a request body with the new java 11 http client?

The only alternative I found is to write the entire output into a `String` or `byte[]` and use `BodyPublishers.ofString/ofByteArray`, however this seems rather inefficient to me for larger requests.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.html#ofInputStream(java.util.function.Supplier). The problem you’re seeing that the J11 client is _reactive_ - i.e. the client will request “more data” and you send it via the `Flow` api; a `BodyPublisher` is actually just a `Flow<ByteBuffer>`. Gson, on the other hand, is based on old pull based, blocking, APIs. You’ll need to either 1) use a JSON serialiser that supports reactive or 2) use `PipelineInputStream` to essentially allow the `Flow` API to block the producing thread - not ideal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Methanol](https://mizosoft.github.io/methanol/)'s [`WritableBodyPublisher`](https://mizosoft.github.io/methanol/writablebodypublisher/). It allows you to stream the request body through an `OutputStream` or a `WritableByteChannel`. The publisher buffers the body in memory as you're writing it. If you want it to get sent while writing you'll need to either use `sendAsync` beforehand or do the writing in another thread. This is somewhat similar to `URLConnection`'s behavior.

```java
var publisher = WritableBodyPublisher.create();
var request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
    .uri(URI.create("https://example.com"))
    .POST(publisher)
    .build();
var responseAsync = client.sendAsync(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());

try (var writer = new OutputStreamWriter(publisher.outputStream())) {
  new Gson().toJson(someJsonObject, writer);
}
```